# Counter adds 1 up again after trying to reset

Tags: javascript, counter

I am trying to reset a counter when failing a test. My `fail()` function is called when something goes wrong after clicking a button. The same button is used for activating the counter, this causes the counter to be 1 instead of 0 when failing. Is there a way to reset the counter without it adding the last click up again?

This is my code example:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#btn-check').click(() => {
        if (checkAnimal(counter)) {
            // Do something.
        }
        else {
            fail(); // Reset counter.
        }

        counter++; // Counter adds 1 again.
    })
})

var counter = 0;

const checkAnimal = (counter) => {
    if (counter < 1) {
        // First animal.
    }
    else {
        // Other animals (different treatment).
    }
}

const fail = () => {
    counter = 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"
        integrity="sha256-r/AaFHrszJtwpe+tHyNi/XCfMxYpbsRg2Uqn0x3s2zc=" crossorigin="anonymous">
        </script>
```

Comment: `checkAnimal`  method is not returning anything!!! what are you trying to do when `#btn-check` button is clicked? can you explain more?

Comment: You are not returning anything hence your function continues to execute irrespective of what it is returned by fail() in else clause

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `counter++` is outside of if/else statement, so after executing else (fail() function), your code will run once more `counter++`.

To avoid that, you will have to replace counter++ to one of the if statement.

Also you are not returning anything in `fail()` function.

```
$(document).ready(() => {
    $('#btn-check').click(() => {
        if (checkAnimal(counter)) {
            // Do something.
        }
        else {
            fail(); // Doesn't return anything.
        }
        // Counter is outside of statement 
        counter++;
    })
})
```